# Does Gramex have inbuild Markdown handler? If yes, how to use that?

Tags: gramex

Trying to create a wiki site similar to gramex help document.
For that, I have `gramex.yaml` that reads

```yaml
url:
  main:
    pattern: /$YAMLURL/
    handler: FileHandler
    kwargs:
      index: false
      path:
        "": $YAMLPATH/{dir}/readme.md
      transform:
        "*.md":
          encoding: utf-8
          function: markdown.markdown(content)
          headers:
            Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
```

File tree looks like:

```
$ tree
.
├── behave
│   └── readme.md
├── gramex.yaml
└── readme.md
```

But it does not seem to render any `MARKDOWN` files as `HTML`.
Do I need to create this markdown.markdown function?
or Is this function readily available in gramex?

---

### Edit 1:

The render issue came because of `{dir}` in `path`.

#### Solution:

Remove `{dir}` and make the new path as :- `$YAMLPATH/readme.md`

---

### EDIT 2: ***NEW PROBLEM***

Markdown tables are not rendered
I have a table in the markdown as:

```
| Criteria | Behave | Pytest |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Readability | Tests are written in natural language format, making them easier to understand by both technical and non-technical stakeholders. | Tests are written in code format, which can be challenging for non-technical stakeholders to understand. |
```

That must be rendered as:

[image]
but the webpage shows:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you change

```yaml
          function: markdown.markdown(content)
```

... to

```yaml
          function: markdown.markdown(content, extensions=['extra'])
```

... it starts working, thanks to the [tables extension](https://python-markdown.github.io/extensions/tables/) which is part of the [extra extension](https://python-markdown.github.io/extensions/extra/).

For more Python markdown options, see https://python-markdown.github.io/reference/.

For extensions, see https://python-markdown.github.io/extensions/